# Single query has 359 results but cte with multi table left join has 396 results. Why?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with a query and 2 tables.  This first query

```
SELECT * FROM B_WORKERACTIVITY
WHERE COURTCASENO IS NULL 
AND WORKCOMMENT IS NOT NULL
```

gives 359 results.  When I left join 2 tables to the query with a cte I get 396 results.  I want to match the 2 tables to the query so that I only have 359 results.  Below is what I've tried doing.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM B_WORKERACTIVITY
WHERE COURTCASENO IS NULL 
AND WORKCOMMENT IS NOT NULL )

SELECT 
cte.*,
a.indssn,
i.firstname,
i.lastname

FROM cte LEFT JOIN TBLASSOC a 
ON cte.REFERRALNO = a.REFERRALNO 
 LEFT JOIN TBLINDIVIDUALS i 
ON i.INDSSN = a.INDSSN ;
```

Comment: You seem to assume that you should get the same number of rows in the output. For that to be true, you must assume that `referralno` is unique in table `tblassoc`, and that `indssn` is unique in table `tblindividuals`. Is that, in fact, the case? (Don't say "yes, that is the case"; perhaps that is the expectation, but it is not enforced. Are there unique constraints, that are enabled and validated?)

Comment: There are duplicate `referralno` in `tblassoc`.  There are only unique `indssn` in `tblindividuals`.  So the result must be including all the duplicate `referralno` from `tblassoc`.  That makes sense and thanks for the help in understanding the concept.

Comment: OK - to see this at work, you may want to run a query that just joins the CTE to the first table, ignoring the second table. You should again see 396 results instead of the expected 356, and for the same reason.

Comment: I did what you said and still got 396 results.  Thanks again!